# How to encrypt a astring in nodeJs that should be used as a an index

Tags: node.js, encryption, koa2

I am designing a microservice architecture using nodeJs and mongoDb. I have a usecase to save driver's license number which also be used to validate the user. Now, as DL number is PII, I don't want to save the string as is, I want to encrypt it before saving. I can use encryption logic to generate a common encrypted string everytime, so I can encrypt the DL number and do a lookup in db. But I am worried about the hackers can decrypt and get all DL numbers if they know the encryption logic for one. Can someone suggest me the best approach for this kind of use case?

Comment: Do you need read this number back to the user or just compare it to an user-inputted value? If the latter, you can hash the value, storing the hash; and compare hashes instead of storing the number, like a password.

Comment: Yep, if you only need to compare values, not actually read and use the value, @Nick 's approach is the best.  If you do need to read the value again in the future, you'll need to both encrypt **and** have an index hash.

Comment: @Nick given how short they are - hashing does not bring any protection against brute-forces.

Comment: @LukeJoshuaPark what kind of index hash could help with search lookups (so that it was of high cardinality) but not reveal too much to recover it using bruteforce?

Comment: @zerkms A keyed hash/HMAC makes brute forcing irrelevant.

Comment: @LukeJoshuaPark right, "like a password" --- I used that as a baseline. Salted hashes (which are generally used to hash passwords) would be insecure, but indeed keyed hashes are okay.

Comment: @Nick, I need to find a record using a DL. if I hash it, then I need to take each DL, compare for each record which is not efficient.

Comment: No, you don't need to do that.  If you only need to *compare* and not *read*, then you should store the driver licences as hashes (from an HMAC).  Then, when you do a lookup, you simply HMAC the provided DL and then do a normal SQL lookup (since you're comparing hashes with hashes).

Answer (score 2):

Ignoring the index for a moment, it sounds like the best approach is to hash the license number using a keyed hash, and store the hash. This is similar to symmetric encryption in that you need to keep a secret, the key. However, it's one-way so attackers that obtain the secret will still need to brute-force each entry to obtain the number.

If the key is compromised, depending on the license number scheme, brute-forcing each number will vary in difficulty from easy to trivial. But, it's better than plaintext.

However, if you really need it as an index you have what appears to be conflicting priorities. I'll defer to someone else, I don't know much about DB indexing.

If it were me and I had time to spare I'd setup one table with the hashes and one with the plaintext license number as an index. Add 10 million rows (or some ceiling that's relevant to you) of test data and profile a few thousand random lookups of each one.

Comment: "will vary in difficulty from easy to trivial" --- I like that! :-)